# Glow Effect on rectangle in iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4

I have take a lot of  patient and make the rectangle in glow effect as per my requirement.

```
CALayer *bevelLayer = [CALayer layer];
[bevelLayer setBounds:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 300.0f, 300.0f)];
[bevelLayer setPosition:CGPointMake(300.0f, 550.0f)];

[bevelLayer setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
[bevelLayer setShadowOpacity:1.0];
[bevelLayer setShadowRadius:7.0f];
[bevelLayer setShadowColor:[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255.0  green:126.0f/255.0f        blue:255.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f] CGColor]];
[bevelLayer setShadowPath:[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(-10.0f, -10.0f, 310.0f, 310.0f) cornerRadius:5.0f] CGPath]];
[[[self view] layer] addSublayer:bevelLayer];
```

Comment: the above code is created in my ipad give the glow effects code is work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of adding a new layer, why dont you directly try it on **self.view**..
Also, shadowOpacity is a value between 0 and 1... So giving 10 is definitely not going to help you.

If you want to try in **self.view**, here is the code:

```
self.view.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor greenColor] CGColor];
self.view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 1);
self.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
self.view.layer.shadowRadius = 20;
```

This way you dont have to worry about the bounds of the layer..